# Error when trying parse json - unexpected character encountered

Tags: android, json, parsing

this is my json format which need to be parsed

```
{
"transaction":
{
  "amount":{
    "total":"122",  
    "currencyCode":"GPP"  
  },
  "qrcode" : "1f0e3dad99908345f7439f8ffabdffop",
  "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
}
}
```

when I parse this i get this error
[image]

this is how I parse my data is

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{" +
                                                  "transaction : "+
                                                    "{"+
                                                      "amount : {" +
                                                        "total : " + amount + ","+  
                                                        "currencyCode : " + currency +  
                                                      "},"+ 
                                                      "qrcode : " + key + "," + 
                                                      "description : " + "This is the payment transaction description." +
                                                    "}" );
request.addHeader(AppConstants.PAYMENT_HEADER1, BEARER);
request.addHeader(AppConstants.content_type, AppConstants.application_json);
    request.setEntity(params);
  try {
      response = httpClient.execute(request);
  entity = response.getEntity();

  inputStream = entity.getContent();                 
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
  sb.append(line + "\n");
 }
result = sb.toString();
Log.e("RESULT", result);
    }catch (Exception ex) {

 Log.e("RESULT_ERROR", ex.toString());
 }
```

have anyopne solved this before....??

Thanks in advance

**SOLVED**

**THANKS TO SUSHANT AND PRAKASH**

I need to format my string json also i was missing out a cuurly brace
Final string is

```
"{" +
    "transaction : "+
    "{"+
    "amount : {" +
    "total : \"" + amount + "\","+ 
    "currencyCode : \"" + currency +  
    "\"},"+ 
    "qrcode : \"" + key + "\"," + 
    "description : " + "\"This is the payment transaction description.\"" +
"}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape double quote while building json string in java.

**The correct one you case is:**

```
new StringEntity("{" +
   "transaction : "+
   "{"+
   "amount : {" +
   "total : \"" + amount + "\","+ 
   "currencyCode : \"" + currency +  
   "\"},"+ 
   "qrcode : \"" + key + "\"," + 
   "description : " + "\"This is the payment transaction description.\"" +
"}" );
```

Comment: Sholdnt also the keys have double quotes?

Comment: Great questions: It depends on the kinds of data you have it it's a numeric, it's not necessary to double quote it.

Comment: @PrakashBhagat could add a curly brace in the end also the string formatting helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You must add " " to all the IDs json (must be escaped with '/'

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{" +
                                              "\"transaction\" :"+ //and so on
```

This makes the content of params

```
{"transaction": //...
```

instead of

```
{transaction: //...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss one closing '}' bracket.

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{" + "\"transaction\" : " + "{"+ "\"amount\" : {" + "\"total\" : " + amount + ","+ "\"currencyCode\" : " + currency + "},"+ "\"qrcode\" : " + key + "," + "\"description\" : " + "This is the payment transaction description." + "}}" );
```

Comment: yes i was missing the bracket also @PrakashBagat gave me a solid example. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It seems it happens because your request JSON string is not built correctly. You have to take your keys and values in double quotes (previously escaped with \):

```
 StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{" + "\"transaction\" : " + "{" + "\"amount\" : {" + "\"total\" : " + "\"" + amount + "\"" + "," + "\"currencyCode\" : " + "\"" + currency + "\" + "}," + "\"qrcode\" : " + "\"" + key + "\"" + "," + "\"description\" : "
        + "\"This is the payment transaction description.\"" + "}");
```